# Issues redirecting HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: apache, apache2, vhosts, apache2.4

I have a site with https on Apache 2.4.7

I want:
http://example.com to forward to https://example.com

Note there is NO trailing slash for this URL!

and

http://example.com/whatever to forward to https://example.com/whatever/

Note there IS a trailing slash for this URL!

Currently I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl.key/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/example.com.ca-bundle

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The above forwards http://example.com to https://example.com correctly.

Unfortunately the above also forwards:

http://example.com/foo/bar to https://example.comfoo/bar as opposed to https://example.com/foo/bar/

Comment: You say you want to redirect `http://example.com/whatever` to `https://example.com/whatever/` and later you say `http://example.com/foo/bar ` should redirect to `https://example.com/foo/bar`. Do you want trailing slash added if it was not present in original request or not?

Comment: Good catch. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Redirect / https://example.com
RedirectMatch ^(/.+)$ https://example.com$1/
```

The current Redirect would only match the home page, I think, so not sure why you were redirected at all for /foo/bar

Also, if this question is really about Apache 2.4, your allow syntax should be `Require all granted` instead 
As in you should replace:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html for more info.

Comment: What should I replace with "Require all granted" and why?

Comment: This worked okay, but this forwards `http://example.com/whatever` to `https://example.com/whatever`, NOT `https://example.com/whatever/` (i.e. with the trailing slash. I only don't want the trailing slash for the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Use rewrite engine. I've got this fragment:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: This forwards `http://example.com` to `https://example.com/` NOT `https://example.com` (i.e. without the trailing slash). Also I think checking the HTTPS condition is not required or else it would have connected via port 443.